# Multidimensional std::valarray and inequalities

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors, valarray

The following piece of code does not compile:

```
#include <valarray>

int main()
{
   std::valarray<std::valarray<int>> a;
   std::valarray<std::valarray<int>> b;
   //std::valarray<std::valarray<bool>> c;
   std::valarray<bool> c;
   c = (a == b);
   return 0;
}
```

Neither of the declarations of ***c*** compile. Is it allowed to use valarray in the above demonstrated manner or are there restrictions on how it should be used.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have the [solution](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a618cb808e1cde5c), though I may be wrong.

Because `begin` and `end` are [non-member overloads](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/valarray/begin/), you use `begin(a)` instead of `a.begin()` and so on.

My choice in using `std::transform` is that you want to iterate over `a` and `b`, compare them, and store the results in `c`, which is why the lambda returns a `std::valarray<bool>` (instead of a `bool`).

```
   std::valarray<std::valarray<int>> a;
   std::valarray<std::valarray<int>> b;
   std::valarray<std::valarray<bool>> c;

   std::transform(begin(a), end(a), begin(b), begin(c),
   [&] (std::valarray<int> a_val, std::valarray<int> b_val) 
       -> std::valarray<bool> {
       return std::valarray<bool>(a_val == b_val);
   });
```

Comment: That is an interesting work around, however the inequality operators having been defined for valarray imply that perhaps such a work around "should" not be required.

Comment: @Rikardo I'm not sure if it's possible though. You're trying to use a single assignment operator for nested valarrays. Of course further research is required, but the workaround was easier to come up with than a reason for why your code would not work (other than the compile errors.)